# MongoDB Shell support for map.set()

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to use the MongoDB shell to run some scripts. Inside the JavaScript I am attempting to run `var map = new Map()` then `map.set(1,1)`.

However, I am getting the following error:

```
E QUERY    [js] TypeError: map.set is not a function :
```

I am running this `mongo` shell version: MongoDB shell version v4.2.1

Does the `mongo` shell not support the `map.set()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, they hide the standard implementation in [implscope.cpp](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/r4.2.1/src/mongo/scripting/mozjs/implscope.cpp)

> // This builtin map is a javascript 6 thing.  We want our version.  so
>   // take theirs out

and implement a new one in [types.js](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/r4.2.1/src/mongo/shell/types.js).

Well, you can workaround doing:

```
Map.prototype.set = Map.prototype.put
```

Answer (score 2):

The MongoDB shell currently implements its own custom `Map` type, rather than the ECMAScript 6 `Map` type.  Amongst the differences, the MongoDB type uses `put` instead of `set` to add elements to the map.  This explains why you're seeing the "map.set is not a function" error.

The three API functions on this custom map type are "get", "put", and "values".

```javascript
> new Map();
{
    "_data" : {
        
    },
    "put" : function(key, value) {
    var o = this._get(key);
    var old = o.value;
    o.value = value;
    return old;
},
    "get" : function(key) {
    return this._get(key).value;
},
    "_get" : function(key) {
    var h = Map.hash(key);
    var a = this._data[h];
    if (!a) {
        a = [];
        this._data[h] = a;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (friendlyEqual(key, a[i].key)) {
            return a[i];
        }
    }
    var o = {key: key, value: null};
    a.push(o);
    return o;
},
    "values" : function() {
    var all = [];
    for (var k in this._data) {
        this._data[k].forEach(function(z) {
            all.push(z.value);
        });
    }
    return all;
}
}
```

MongoDB issue [SERVER-46243](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-46243) was created in February 2020, and proposes to use the standard ECMAScript `Map` type instead.  Once this change is implemented, your current code will work.

In summary, your example code should work as is if you change `set` to `put`:

```javascript
var map = new Map();
map.put(1, 1);
```

---

Note that this is no longer an issue in the new `mongosh` [MongoDB Shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell) (currently in Beta), as it uses the standard ECMAScript 6 `Map` type.  This was mention in an April 2021 comment on the aforementioned ticket:

> this feature is available in our new MongoDB Shell (`mongosh`) [...]. `mongosh` is still in beta but it should have most of the functionality you need. [...] we are preparing to GA it later this year [...].